# How i can referecne nested classes inside my scss

Tags: css, typescript, sass

I have the following .scss file:=

```
.singleNews {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: $font-family;
  font-size: $font-size;
  font-weight: $regular-font-weight;

  &__image {
    padding: 5em;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

    &.featured {
      height: 75%;
    }
  }
}
```

so how i can define the featured? i tried the following but all failed:-

```
import styles from './SingleNews.module.scss';
//code goes here...
<div className={styles.singleNews__image__featured} style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${post.image})` }}/> 
<div className={styles.singleNews__image featured} style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${post.image})` }}/> 
<div className={styles.singleNews__image.featured} style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${post.image})` }}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`&.featured` selects the the parent selector with the class `featured`, which means that the div need have the classes `singleNews__image` and `featured`

```css
.singleNews__image.featured {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

/* Same selector with Sass */
/*
.singleNews {
  &__image {
    &.featured {
      background-color: blue;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
    }
  }
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="singleNews__image featured">
</div>
```